# how to get the row number in uitable view,it contains certtain number of sections

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

all i need to do is how to get the particular section  number and its row number in an uitableview...mainly the table contains 20 number of sections.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To get a meaningful answer please read the FAQ with instructions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and a personal favorite of mine: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

you are getting the values in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   NSLog(%@"%d", indexPath.row);
   NSLog(%@"%d", indexPath.section);

}
```

for getting number of rows in particuler section then use

```
   [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];
```

EDIT:-

```
UITableViewCell* cell = (UITableViewCell*)button.superview;
```

here you'l get the selected cell and by using this cell you can change the values of the label.

for getting indexpath value when click on button use this line of code,

```
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [yourtableviewname indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)sender.superview];
    NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
```

Comment: @ Krishna1251:if this answer helps you then accept it for clean up community.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the [`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3adidSelectRowAtIndexPath%3a) method. The `NSIndexPath` argument has a `section` and `row` property you can access.

Answer (score 0):

Find selected indexPath: `NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForSelectedRow];` and then use `NSUInteger selectedRow = selectedRowIndexPath.row;` to get selected row and `NSUInteger selectedSection = selectedRowIndexPath.section;` to get selected section.

Answer (score -1):

Implement

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
int row=indexPath.row;
int section=indexPath.section
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When the user taps a row

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //section:
    NSInteger section = indexpath.section

    //row:
    NSinteger row= indexpath.row    
}
```

is called.